# Postgres Rails DB Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

I have just created a new RoR project on a Godaddy VPS running Ubuntu. The app is set up to run Postgres, which is installed and running.

Wwhen I do the INITIAL rake, I get:

```
server$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate
FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/........
```

Here is my database yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: philip
  password: ###    
test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username: philip
  password: ### - not real 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username: philip
  password: ###
```

I have tried `root` and `philip`.
And I have created roles and users in PG for both.

Comment: Regardless of my database.yml, rake complains about root

Comment: I guess there is another file

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, PostgreSQL by default is configured to allow local connections over Unix socket only to authenticate with the same username as the connecting Unix user.

You are running your app as `root` in your OS. And PostgreSQL forces you to use `root` as a database user name. If you want it to use a different database account, you need to run your app as a different user.

Apparently, your PostgreSQL server doesn't have a `root` account.

- [Ubuntu wiki page about PostgreSQL setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL)

A dirty fix could be authentication over TCP/IP: set a `host` to `127.0.0.1` in your `database.yml`, and these restrictions won't have any effect.
Another way to circumvent it is to edit `pg_hba.conf` to not require "the same user" for local connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the roles and database by hand:

SSH into the vps and then ...

Switch into the default user:

```
sudo su – postgres
```

Once logged in as this user, you can create the new role:

```
createuser
Enter name of role to add: philip
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

To outfit your user with a password, you can add the words –pwprompt to the createuser command:

```
createuser --pwprompt
```

Source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Yeah that's strange that it keeps saying "root".

Answer (score 0):

I started over by deleting all roles in PG.  I recreated what I needed and it is all good